# morse function and immersion

Tags: differential-topology

I have a question from Pollack and Guillemin's book:
let $X$ be a smooth manifold.
$f:X\to \mathbb R^n$ an immersion, $f=(f_1,....f_n)$.
show that for almost all $a_1,...,a_n$, the function
$a_1f_1+.....a_nf_n$ is a morse function on $X$.
I know so far that if the thm. is true locally it will be true because I can get countable open cover for $X$ but I can't prove it yet.
the hint says to read the proof for the case X sits inside R^k but I don't understand the proof.
I would like for some help,

I add a link for it :
http://www.cs.unicam.it/piergallini/home/materiale/geom4/testi/Guillemin-Pollack:Differential%20topology.pdf
the question is in page 48 question 21.
the proof is in page 43-44,
thanks